# ImportError: cannot import name '_path'

Tags: matplotlib

i must install matplotlib on a offline PC with python 3.5....to run some scripts. I copy the lib to the Right path on the offline PC....all other lib like reportlab are running. But if i trie to write something with matplotlib.pyplot as plt i got the Error Message "ImportError:cannot Import 'path'".
a the first step i 
Import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('aggs') 
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

the biggest Problem i cant download something on this offline pc.

So i am rly new to write some codes with python so pls dont jugde me guys =)

So the frist step was delet the old libs and use older versions of matplotlib
actuel i use 3.0.2.

i copy the Folders matplotlib, matplotlib-3.0.2.dist-info and matplotlib-3.0.2-py3.5-nspkg.pth

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')             
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9.5, 6), dpi=450)

ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(tick_scale_x))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(tick_scale_y))

plt.title(dia_title, fontsize=20, color='black')
plt.xlabel(axis_label_x)
plt.ylabel(axis_label_y)
```

Comment: You cannot copy an installed version of matplotlib to another computer. Instead you need to install it on that other machine. So you need to download the wheel file, copy it to your offline machine and install it there.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help….yeah i have the .whl file from matplotlib but is not possible to install it with pip …. i got everytime a error message pip cannot using ""...but my Code is …..pip install some.whl in the cmd